# Spring Data concurrency

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, java-stream

I want to get data from H2 database concurrently. I wanted to do it through parallel stream, but I am getting wrong results with parallel stream. With normal stream it returns right result (only one SELECT returns result others returns null). I am not able to find where is the problem. I look like in concurrent access to repository. Can you help?

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @Id
    private String carType;

    public String getCarType() {
        return carType;
    }

    public void setCarType(String carType) {
        this.carType = carType;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
public interface CarsRepository extends Repository<Car, String> {
    void save(Car car);

    Car findOneByCarType(String carType);
}
```

Service:

```
  @Service
public class CarsServiceImpl implements CarsService {

    @Autowired
    private CarsRepository carsRepository;

    @Override
    public void save(Car car) {
        carsRepository.save(car);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Car> getCars(List<String> carsTypes) {
        return carsTypes.parallelStream()
                .map(carType -> Optional.ofNullable(carsRepository.findOneByCarType(carType)))
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class CarsServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private CarsService carsService;

    @Test
    public void getCars() {
        List<String> carsTypes = Arrays.asList("audi", "ford", "opel");
        carsTypes.forEach(
                carType -> {
                    Car car = new Car();
                    car.setCarType(carType);
                    carsService.save(car);
                }
        );

        List<Car> cars = carsService.getCars(carsTypes);
        Assert.assertEquals(carsTypes.size(), cars.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the actual problem? this test fails on parallel stream but works on sequential stream?

Comment: Yes. I don't think there should be problem with concurrent access but there is and I don't know why...

Comment: What are "wrong results"?

Comment: As you see. I store three cars. When I try to get them in from parallel stream, I get only one car. Others are null. When I run it in sequential stream, I get three cars as expected.

Comment: Only main thread returns result, when I run code in separate thread pool, nothing is returned. Probably race condition because some component (entity manager?) is not thread safe.